# How to detect if the user has an extended desktop/display in Java?

Tags: java, screen, awt

My problem is simple and I believe I am just missing something minor, but I can not figure out what it is.

I know how to use GraphicsEnvironment, GraphicsConfiguration, and GraphicsDevice. I know how to get all the showing devices etc., etc.. And I know how to display to a specific device.

The only thing I can't figure out is if the user's desktop is extended, duplicated, or showing to an individual monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GraphicsDevice` is not necessarily equivalent to a hardware device, but to a 'display' that can be used by the Java application. So, when the user's desktop is duplicated or showing an individual monitor, even if there's a second monitor (hardware) connected or not,  `getScreenDevices` (from `GraphicsEnvironment`) shows only one GraphicsDevice. Thus, I believe that you won't be able to identify these settings using this Java API.

Your solution probably will require JNI code. The project [Lightweight Java Game Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/?source=directory) has something like that, [take a look at the Display class](http://java-game-lib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/java-game-lib/trunk/LWJGL/src/java/org/lwjgl/util/Display.java?revision=3838&view=markup).

Comment: I appreciate the response. This definitely seems like a step in the right direction. I will explore this library and hopefully see if it can solve my problem. Thanks!!